Is it possible to install custom ROM on LG K10 (2017)?
I love my phone LG K10 2017 (LG M250E) the way it looks, the way it feels when I hold it, and all but the OS, I just don't like it.
Custom ROMs are like a new thing for me. I don't know how to do it, but I want my phone to be more customisable and all.
Can anyone help me find out if I can install a custom Android ROM from Android 10 to 14, it would be very helpful.

The phone has only 2GB RAM which is not much for newer Android versions. You are also a bit late, custom ROM development and availability decreases over time. Unless you have a very popular high-end device, after ~5-6 years usually ROM development ends as the ROM developer has switched to a newer device.
